# Is it advisable to provide IDs or let stripe handle that

Tags: stripe-payments

When creating customers, products and plans on stripe via the api, is it better to supply my own id so that the id of each customer, product and plan on stripe are in sync with their respective id in my database table or its better to just let stripe generate id for me and then I save in my database.

Kindly provide reasons to support why you think one approach is better.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata -- *"Attach your system's unique IDs to a Stripe object, for easy lookups. For example, add your order number to a charge, your user ID to a customer or recipient, or a unique receipt number to a transfer."*

Comment: add to @Robert Harvery's answer. Personally i will recommend using Stripe default ID. 
1) To your system, Stripe is an 3rd party system, you should not rely on 3rd party system API as your data storage as Stripe now supports passing your own ID but you are not sure if that will always be the case. 
2) Storing your own customer id vs Stripe generate id will make your system more extensible; let's say in the future you decide to use Paypal's customer API, you might simple swap the stripe cust id or they could co exists with Stripe if that makes sense

Comment: thanks a lot for this @wsw , this is very helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: *[shrug]* -- Nothing is ever guaranteed.